# Is there a way to enable wireless debugging on an Android 8.0 device?

Tags: android, adbwireless

I've been able to use wireless debugging on an Android 11 phone over Visual Studio on Mac, mainly because it explicitly has 'Wireless Debugging' option.

But I couldn't find similar option on an Android 8 phone.
So is it possible to debug wirelessly on older Android phones?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can but its not completely wireless you will have to connect via USB once forward the port then have adb debugging over wifi
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless)

1. Connect the device via USB with "USB debugging enabled"
2. run `adb tcpip 5555`
3. Disconnect the USB cable from the target device
4. find local ip of the device on the network
5. run `adb connect device_ip_address:5555`

Comment: thanks for the response, but I wasn't able to get it working.
I ensured that both my Android 8.0 phone and the Mac are on the same WiFi network, and enabled USB debugging on the Android phone. 
Running 'adb tcpip 555' on Mac's terminal worked fine stating 'Restarting in TCP mode port:5555' however running the command 'adb connect <ip_address_ofAndroid>:5555 always returns "Failed to connect to <ip_address_ofAndroid>: Connection refused.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @zeuschyant8 check if there is any firewall blocking port 5555.